# How to add extra spaces before each row before printing the matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to print the matrix named 'Transfer' using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Transfer=[[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]]
s=[[str(e) for e in row] for row in Transfer]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print '\n'.join(table)
```

However, the output in the terminal is aligned to the left, and I would like to add a few spaces before each row, so that the matrix looks centered. Where/how should I add the spaces in this code for it to work correctly?

Comment: Wouldn't the amount of spaces required be dependent on the width of your terminal?

Comment: Centered how? All your values are the same length (3 characters), so they _already_ appear centered.

Comment: @Nathan Absolutely, but I'll be happy if I can add a few spaces in front of each row, let's say four or five, so that the matrix doesn't look stuck to the left.

Comment: You can't really control the 'centredness', but a simple way to do what you want is something like `spaces = '    '; print spaces + '\n%s'.join(table) % spaces`.

Comment: Add `fmt = ' '*5 + fmt`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't want the matrix to look glued to the left side of the terminal, I'd like to add a few spaces in front of each row. I meant I want to see the matrix "centered" in the terminal, not perfectly of course, just not aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center on some width:

```
print('\n'.join(r.center(80) for r in table))
```

Or just add spaces on the left:

```
print('\n'.join('    ' + r for r in table))
```